# Calling exceptions of the same code in different operating systems

Tags: lua

I can't understand why my demo code written in Lua only works on Windows.

```
local supermodule = {}

function supermodule.Test1()
    return print("Function 1")
end

return supermodule
```

and

```
local supermodule = require("supermodule")
local sp = supermodule.Test1
sp()
```

This demo code runs on Windows, but crashes with an error that it cannot find the module on Linux and Mac OS. How can I fix this?

Comment: `package.path` (list of directories to seach for a Lua module) is different on Win/Linux.

Comment: @ESkri what do I need to do to make my scripts more versatile? So that they work everywhere?

Comment: Make sure you have `cd` to the directory where your script and modules are located.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because `print()` returns nothing?
Try it without `return` or `return` after `print()` something.
Example
supermodule.lua

```
#!/usr/local/bin/lua
-- supermodule.lua
return({["Test1"] = function() print("Function 1") return end})
```

(The SHEBANG is not used but show it will be ignored when required)
Example of use

```
$ lua -i -e 'supermodule = require("supermodule") sp = supermodule.Test1 sp()'
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
Function 1
>
```

Path in `require()`
Lets say you have `supermodule.lua` in: `./sumod/supermodule.lua`
Than require it from `./` with: `require("sumod.supermodule")`
That works on Windows/Linux/Mac OS.